# Creating text file without using bcp in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to query a table and print the output in a text file. I have a normal user login with dbo permission on the database. I cannot use bcp or cannot give any special permissions. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a text file on the server or elsewhere with only permissions in the database. There are several alternatives to [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) ([SQLCLR](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2341/use-the-sql-server-clr-to-read-and-write-text-files/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), [sp_OACreate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/ff28c480-d21b-4676-a6c1-752fcd8b612a), [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx), etc.) but Windows is a little more secure than just letting any database user write to the file system. Imagine if anybody running a query against your database could write to the file system? ([Some background here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/sqlnetfx/thread/b4b44b28-1008-47c7-876d-2e1d27d12cfa).)

Here is an article that describes how others have done it, as well as some ensuing discussions:

- [Reading and Writing Files in SQL Server using T-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/)

For the CLR approach there is also a codeplex project called [FileSystemHelper](http://filesystemhelper.codeplex.com/) which will be more useful than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the query manually, SSMS has an option to output results to file (CTL-Shift-F)